# How to fix invalid interaction in Pycord

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycord

When I try to call my interaction (/clyde message:message), I get an error which says that the interaction is not found.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "W:\\Users\\Артём\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\discord\\bot.py", 
  line 1114, in invoke_application_command await ctx.command.invoke(ctx) 
File "W:\\Users\\Артём\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\discord\\commands\\core.py", 
  line 375, in invoke await injected(ctx) 
File "W:\\Users\\Артём\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\discord\\commands\\core.py", 
  line 132, in wrapped raise ApplicationCommandInvokeError(exc) from exc discord.errors.ApplicationCommandInvokeError: 
     Application Command raised an exception: NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10062): Unknown interaction
```

My code is:

```
import discord
import clydeapi
clyd = clydeapi.AI()

token = "token"

bot = discord.Bot()

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Logged in as {bot.user}")

@bot.command()
async def clyde(ctx, message: discord.Option(str)):
    a = clyd.send(message)
    await ctx.respond(a)

bot.run(token)
```

I've tried running the interaction using /clyde message:Hi, Clyde!, and I expected it to use the Clyde API and get the response. But what happened, is that it gave me an Unknown Interaction error.

Does anyone know how to fix this?